# Couple, few and several

Tags: grammar, word-usage

During typical conversation, how would one define *couple*, *few* and *several*?  I have read the actual definitions; however, they appear to be a bit vague.  My thoughts are:

- A couple is two.
- A few is three to five.
- Several is six to 11.
- After 11 is obviously a dozen...

What is the consensus among us rational people?  Please do not get too literal.

Comment: None of your "definitions" is correct in any way. There's no relation between the broadly-defined commonly-used idiomatic expressions *a couple, a few, several, ...* and discrete numbers. There's a good reason why the dictionaries are "a bit vague:" the words are *supposed* to give a vague idea, not put a concrete number on something. You get the idea.

Comment: If I'm talking about a group of five people, and four of them drink beer, that is not _a few of them_. I agree that assigning definite numbers to these expressions is futile. The only one that _literally_ would give a number is indeed _a couple_ but even that is not always two. If I go out with _a couple of people_, there's likely more than three in total. (If I go out with _a couple_, there are exactly three of us though!)

Comment: @oerkelens I have no period of this but it seems from the UK that the use of "couple" to mean more than 2 is more prevalent -- or more accepted -- in the US than here.